# Datastax c# Cassandra driver throws SyntaxError when trying to create a table using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, cassandra, datastax

I have encountered an exception while trying to create a table with Datastax c# driver. Here's some code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoints("localhost").Build())
        using (var session = cluster.Connect())
        {
            session.CreateKeyspaceIfNotExists("Test");
            session.ChangeKeyspace("Test");

            session.GetTable<Foo>().CreateIfNotExists();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [Table("foos")]
    private class Foo
    {
        [ClusteringKey(1)]
        [Column("fooId")]
        public string FooId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code I get 'SyntaxtError: line 1:46 no viable alternative at input ','' at this line:

```
session.GetTable<Foo>().CreateIfNotExists();
```

If I replace the line with something like this, it works just fine:

```
session.Execute(@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foos (fooId varchar PRIMARY KEY);");
```

I'm using CassandraCSharpDriver v1.0.4 (from nuget) and local Cassandra v2.0.6.

Am I doing something wrong? I was unable to find cause of this error, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I ended up writing my own extension method with limited functionality.